# Continuity for elementary functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I read the following theorem:

> All elementary functions are partially dierentiable in all variables in the interior of their maximal domain except the norm when the argument is $0$ and the powers with exponent $α ∈ (0,1)$ when the argument is $0$.

But I don't get what is the meaning of **the powers with exponent $α \in (0,1)$ when the argument is $0$**. And why is this true? Can you help me with an example please?

Comment: Think about the single variable case where $\alpha \in (0, 1)$. For example, the derivative of $x^{1/2} = \frac{1}{2x^{1/2}}$. What is the limit of this derivative as $x \to 0$?

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x)=x^{\alpha}$ for $0<\alpha<1$. That is the function they are talking about when they said "the powers with exponent $\alpha\in(0,1)$". This function does not have a derivative at $x=0$, here $x$ is the argument.